# image to html using mpld3

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

I am trying to export the html of a graph using `mpld3`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
obj, = plt.plot([3,1,4,1,5], 'ks-', mec='w', mew=5, ms=20)
mpld3.save_html(obj,'C:\\Users\\prabhat.mishra\\Desktop\\figure.html')
```

Facing Issue as `AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no attribute 'canvas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the `solution`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
fig = plt.figure()
obj, = plt.plot([3,1,4,1,5])
mpld3.save_html(fig,"C:\\Users\\prabhat.mishra\\Desktop\\figure1.html")
```

You need to pass figure object to `save_html`